# iPhone Camera and Image Chooser

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, iphone-sdk-3.0, uiimagepickercontroller

I have found a lot of information on using UIImagePickerController to let the user choose the image they want from the Photos application's data.  I am wondering how I can create this same effect on 3.0, as it doesn't seem as if a lot of the old code works anymore.  In addition, I would like the user to be able to take a new picture from this same pop-up.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Works in 3.0, same as before; I don't believe there were any changes.  I just alloc/init a UIImagePickerController, and pass it to presentModalViewController, like this:

```
- (void) chooseImageFromLibrary {
    if( ![UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary] ) return;

    UIImagePickerController *imagePickerController = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    imagePickerController.delegate = self;
    imagePickerController.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
    imagePickerController.allowsImageEditing = YES;
    [self presentModalViewController:imagePickerController animated:YES];
}

- (void) chooseImageFromCamera {
    if( ![UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera] ) return;

    UIImagePickerController *imagePickerController = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    imagePickerController.delegate = self;
    imagePickerController.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
    imagePickerController.allowsImageEditing = YES;
    [self presentModalViewController:imagePickerController animated:YES];
}
```

Implement the delegate methods, too:

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker 
        didFinishPickingImage:(UIImage *)image 
                  editingInfo:(NSDictionary *)editingInfo {
    // Do something with the image here.

    [[picker parentViewController] dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}

- (void)imagePickerControllerDidCancel:(UIImagePickerController *)picker {
    [[picker parentViewController] dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

Comment: Hi zpasternack: What would my .h file look like for these functions... What would the class have to conform to?